# How to check in C # that a message sent by a producer has successfully reached the Kafka server?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I can't find a way to confirm that a message sent to the Kafka server has been received correctly by the server.
I need a confirmation that the message was sent and received correctly in order to act on the C # code in case the message was not received by the server.
I have read that there is a property called ack to configure that, but I can't find how to receive such confirmation.

Comment: Could you provide your code or similar example? I think you could only get information about sending process.

Comment: It sounds like you're bumping into the [two generals' problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem).

Comment: @Flater Except that would only apply if Kafka brokers didn't respond, in which case, Kafka clients have built-in retry mechanisms, which may repeat messages, but it certainly isn't "unreliable"

Comment: @Crowley77 Please use the checkmark next to the answers if they've solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a DeliveryReport handler

Refer documentation - https://docs.confluent.io/clients-confluent-kafka-dotnet/current/overview.html

Async

```
var t = producer.ProduceAsync("topic", new Message<Null, string> { Value="hello world" });
t.ContinueWith(task => {
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...

        Console.WriteLine($"Wrote to offset: {task.Result.Offset}");
    }
});
```

Synchronous

```
public static void handler(DeliveryReport<Null, string>)
{
    ...
}

public static process(...)
{
    ...
    producer.Produce(
        "my-topic", new Message<Null, string> { Value = "hello world" }, handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
bool messagePublished;
var result = await _producer.ProduceAsync(yourTopic, yourMessage);

if (result.Status == PersistenceStatus.Persisted)
    messagePublished = true;
```

Notice that you have multiple `PersistenceStatus` values.

You can find more info on the official [confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/_site/api/Confluent.Kafka.PersistenceStatus.html).